# Configure the behaviour of R linters in Sublime 3

Tags: json, r, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

I am using [`lintr`](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) in `Sublime 3` via [`SublimeLinter 3`](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) and the [`SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr`](https://github.com/jimhester/SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr) plugin. On the `lintr` `README.md` file there is a [short mention](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr#configuration-2) on how to configure what linters should be used:

```
{
  "user": {
    "linters": {
      "r": {
        "linters": "with_defaults(line_length_linter(120))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am using it in conjunction with `SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr` and I can't get it to work. My `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` file looks like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": true,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "linters": {
            "lintr": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "cache": "TRUE",
                "excludes": [],
                "linters": "default_linters"
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": [
                "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64"
            ]
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "r extended": "r"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

The `lintr` package has a bunch of linters (see [this link](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr#available-linters)). What I would live to achieve is to discard some of them (i.e., not use, for instance, `assignment_linter`). Do you have any idea how to achieve this? It should be possible, right?

---

**Edit 1:**

I noticed that by changing `"linters": "default_linters"` to `"linters": "assignment_linter"`, only the errors falling under `assignment_linter` will be picked. I tried to expand it using an array, but it doesn't work:

```
...
"lintr": {
    "@disable": false,
    "args": [],
    "cache": "TRUE",
    "excludes": [],
    "linters": [
        "assignment_linter",
        "object_name_linter"
    ]
}
...
```

Inside the `Sublime 3` console, the message error message with this attempt is: `Error: unexpected '[' in "lint(cache = TRUE, commandArgs(TRUE), ["`.

---

**Edit 2:** possible solution

Looking at `with_defaults` inside the `lintr` package I found two ways of choosing only the linters I am interested in. Assuming that I only want `assignment_linter` and `no_tab_linter`, the configuration is:

- `"linters": "default_linters[c('assignment_linter', 'no_tab_linter')]"` or
- `"linters": "with_defaults(assignment_linter, no_tab_linter, default = NULL)"`

It works, but are there other less error-prone approaches? With this approach if I want to discard just one linter I have to list all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question for "Edit 2", you can discard a single linter as follows:

```
{
  "user": {
    "linters": {
      "r": {
        "linters": "with_defaults(some_default_linter = NULL)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... where `some_default_linter` is the name of a linter from the list `lintr::default_linters`.

Comment: Oh, looks like what I was looking for.